# How to Schedule Http Post Service deployed on Azure App Service Web App from Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-scheduler

This is the Azure App Service Web App ->
`https://dev*******api.azurewebsites.net/`

This is the Http Post Service ->
`https://dev*******api.azurewebsites.net/api/myItem/myPublisher`

How can I schedule Http Post Service to run everyday from Azure ?

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

There is a service would meet your need: **WebJob**.

> WebJobs is a feature of Azure App Service that enables you to run a
> program or script in the same instance as a web app, API app, or
> mobile app. There is no additional cost to use WebJobs.

You could consider [creating a scheduled WebJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#CreateScheduledCRON). Configure the CRON Expression as:  `0 0 0 * * *` to run your background task everyday.